# How to uninstall CourseSmart software in OSX

Tags: macos, uninstall

I downloaded this program from CourseSmart. I logged into it and told it to remember me. The problem is that I used the wrong account. I can't find a way to log out so that I can log in with a different account. I tried moving the program to the trash and reinstalling it. This didn't work though, because when I moved the program back into the Applications folder somehow it still remembered my old account. How can I uninstall this so that when I install it again it doesn't remember my account?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Mac OS X is a multi-user system. Application preferences are never* stored in the application bundle. Application Preferences are stored somewhere in a user's `~/Library/`.

---

Check to see if there is a file in `~/Library/Preferences` whose name starts with `com.coursesmart.`. If there is, delete it. Other possibilities are a folder `CourseSmart` or a folder with the same name as the application in `~/Library/Application Support`. Delete everything you find.

Comment: Another possibility is to launch the application, maybe even change one or two settings, and quit. Then order `~/Library/Preferences` by modification date. The preferences file of the application is most likely near the very top.

Comment: I found a file with coursesmart in the filename in ~/Library/Preferences and deleted it. All it did was cause the program to redisplay some confirmation dialog on startup. However, after the program was started, it still remembered my account.

Comment: @OSX Another option is a keychain entry (like Safari stored passwords, or mail accounts). Open `/Applications/Utilities/Keychain Access` and look for something related to CourseSmart there (perhaps order by date). If you find nothing, use [fseventer](http://www.fernlightning.com/doku.php?id=software:fseventer:start) or the command-line application `fs_usage` to find out which files are accessed or perhaps modified when launching/quitting this application. Remove all of them that are within your home folder and look like they are connected to this program.

Comment: @OSXJedi Anything new? Topic was pushed to front by Community.

Comment: Wasn't able to uninstall it. I just installed it in Windows running in a virtual machine and use it there. It would be nice to just be able to run it in OSX though. I would like to think that OSX is better than Windows, but this is one example where it isn't. How did the question get pushed to the front?

Comment: @OSXJedi The OS is as good as the applications. If they don't work as one expects (i.e. Keychain and Defaults), there's nothing the OS can do about it. Have you tried looking into Keychain and fseventer/`fs_usage` as I suggested? You can also look into the installer you used for clues to where the application writes during installation. At least this'll give you a clean uninstall. // A few unanswered, open questions will be bumped to the front page once an hour by [Community](http://superuser.com/users/-1/community). Just search the front page for "Community", you'll always see a few of them.